# Create SFX on the command-line where the SFX extracts silently to a predefined path?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, self-extracting

I use this command-line to create a self-extracting archive with 7z:

```
7z.exe a -sfx -y a.exe *.txt
```

This creates "a.exe" containing the specified text files and extracts them ALMOST silently (a console window is shown for a fraction of a second).

How can I create the self-extracting archive without showing a console window AT ALL when extracting and predefine an extraction path (e.g. %temp%\mydir)?

OS: Windows 7